# Flot Chart: setup data chart in object format

Tags: flot

From doc [Data Format](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md):

```
The data is an array of data series:

[ series1, series2, ... ]
A series can either be raw data or an object with properties. The raw data format is an array of points:

[ [x1, y1], [x2, y2], ... ]
E.g.

[ [1, 3], [2, 14.01], [3.5, 3.14] ]
```

I have data in format:

```
[
   {Date: "03-15-2016", Rank: 50}, 
   {Date: "03-16-2016", Rank: 77},
   {Date: "03-17-2016", Rank: 63},
]
```

So it's an array with nested objects. But my chart was not built. According to doc, series can be an object with properties.

How to built line chart using an object with properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A series can be an object with properties, but the data property of a series object has to be an array of datapoints (which also have to be arrays).

Comment: I converted object to an array, so now it looks like [[1325347200000, 50]] and it works. thanks!!